# recyclerView won't scroll smoothly for first time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a recyclerView inside a fragment, this fragment is located in a viewpager2.

I read data from server and convert them to my ModelClass, them create an ArrayList and pas this array list to recyclerView.
here is my recyclerView item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/main_icon_background"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/vazir_font"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textAppearance="@style/vazir_font"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@color/gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/source"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/vazir_font"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textAppearance="@style/vazir_font"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my recyclerView adapter:

```
class NewsRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val items = ArrayList<NewsAdapterModel>()
    lateinit var onClick: NewsTutorialClickListener

    fun add(list: ArrayList<NewsAdapterModel>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_recycler_model, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return items[position].id.hashCode().toLong()
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun binding(model: NewsAdapterModel) {


            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onClick.onClick(model.id)
            }


            itemView.title.text = model.title
            itemView.description.text = model.description
            itemView.date.text = Arrange().persianConverter(model.date)
            itemView.source.text = model.source

            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .load(model.image)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.logo)
                .into(itemView.image)

        }
    }

}
```

I used this recycler view in my fragment just like this:

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        adapter.onClick = this
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)


        scope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                fetchNews()
            }
        }
    }
```

my problem is : when I scroll recycler view for first time it is not smooth and it seems some frames are jumped, but when I reach end of recyclerView and scroll to up then scroll down it is very smooth and find. how can I solve this issue?
I also should mention that Items of recyclerView are not much, it's around 10 items.

Comment: try removing both binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)

Comment: @Rinat in fact, it get better! thanks! I search a lot and lots of people were saying use these two method to increase recyclerView performance. it was interesting.

Comment: does it count as an answer? did it accomplish what you were looking for? If, yes i can add answer explaining why this happened.

Comment: yes! I'll be grateful to know why this happened @Rinat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

actually it can cause no harm and indeed improves performance, because recyclerView won't bother calculating size of viewHolders evrytime inside `onBindViewHolder`. But you have all your `TextViews` with `wrap_content` height which will most certainly cause some broken UI in future.

---

remove

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
```

This function forces `RecyclerView` to prematurely inflate and bind 20 extra `ViewHolders`, so that it can use them straight away without calling `OncreateViewHolder` and `OnBindViewHolder`. You should'nt play around with this and just go with the defaults. Although **20** extra viewholders shouldn't have been a big deal, i guess maybe `RecyclerView` got confused because you forced it create extra **20** on top of existing **10**, while you list only contains **10** items. It was taking time to create those extra viewHolders blocking ui thread, but after they were created it seemed smooth.

Comment: removing: recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize() did the work for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add these lines

```
        binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
```

Please remove these lines